# Change directory for Kate syntax highlighting files

Tags: kde, kde4, syntax-highlighting, kate

I'm running Standard Debian Wheezy with KDE 4.8.4 and Kate 3.8.4.

The Kate text editor's syntax highlighting files are located in:

```
/usr/share/kde4/apps/katepart/syntax
```

If I run

```
kde4-config --prefix
```

this gives

```
/usr
```

and *$KDEDIR* is empty. This results in that only XML files in the upper direcory are used for highlighting.

In several other forums, I saw that it should work to create a folder "syntax" in

```
~/.kde/share/apps/katepart/
```

If I put syntax-highlighting files there on my system, they appear to be ignored.

How can someone change/set the directory for the syntax-highlighting files used by *Kate* to an arbitrary directory?

Comment: I'm using Debian Wheezy, KDE 4.8.4, Kate 3.8.4 and the current directory is: `/usr/share/kde4/apps/katepart/syntax`

Comment: You're right. This was only typo. I corrected this in my question, thanks.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/67o0sd/how_to_add_custom_syntax_highligthing_in_kate/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution just by chance:

Settings -> Kate config -> Open/Save -> File types

If I click on "Download syntax-highlighting files", all files which are already installed and can be updated (a newer version is available) are marked here. Then a click on "Install" updates alle these files. After that the folder

```
~/.kde/share/apps/katepart/syntax
```

exists and includes all installed *XML* files. Now I can add additional files to that folder or can modify the existing files therein. The modifications will be applied after restarting *Kate*.

This solves my problem for the moment. But I don't understand why it works in this way! (Maybe someone can comment on that)

The other open task is how one can choose a different folder for the *XML* files.

Comment: As of katepart5, the standard directory is now ~/.local/share/katepart5/syntax

Comment: The directory is now ~/.local/share/org.kde.syntax-highlighting/syntax

Answer (score 3):

For the latest version of Kate, placing syntax xml files in this directory works:

```
~/.local/share/katepart5/syntax
```

Thanks @Datalore

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't change the directory, but it worked anyway for me. Manually create this directory and place the highlight XMLs there:

```
$HOME/.local/share/org.kde.syntax-highlighting/syntax/
```

And don't forget to restart Kate afterwards!

Source: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kate/katepart/highlight.html