# How to enable commenting of .asy files in Kate?

Tags: kde, kate

How to enable commenting of .asy files in Kate?

In the Kate editor, for some types of files, one can comment and uncomment lines by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. But, in Kate's default configuration, this is not possible for .asy files (associated with [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/doc/index.html#SEC_Contents)). Nothing happens if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is pressed (and also nothing happens if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> is pressed, and the 'Toggle comment' is grayed out in Tools).

The appropriate commenting symbol for .asy files is `//`.

I thought the solution could be if Kate had the proper highlighting .xml file for .asy files. I found the instructions for generating that file [here](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/doc/Editing-modes.html). The relevant directory (the one containing the script `asy-kate.sh`) was a bit different for me (`/usr/share/asymptote/` rather than `/usr/local/share/asymptote`). Also, the script `asy-kate.sh` needed the file `asy-keywords.el`, and was complaining that it was missing. I found that file elsewhere in my system (in `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/`) and I copied it to `/usr/share/asymptote/`. Now `asy-kate.sh` ran without problems, and produced a reasonable-looking `asymptote.xml` file.

The next question was where to put it. After some googling, two candidate directories turned up: `~/.kde/share/apps/katepart/syntax/` and `~/.local/share/katepart5/syntax/`. I created them and placed `asymptote.xml` in both. I restarted Kate, but unfortunately the new .xml files seemed to have no effect: for one, nothing was highlighted in my .asy files, and, more important for my purposes, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> still wasn't working and 'Toggle comment' was still grayed out.

How can I configure kate so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> work properly with .asy files?

Here is my system:

Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-70-generic
OS Type: 64-bit

The Kate version is 19.12.3.

Answer (score 1):

Using Kate 20.12.3 from KDE Plasma Desktop 5.21.3.

Inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108685/315749), I created a custom theme (in Kate, Settings → Configure Kate → Open/Save → Modes & Filetypes) to let the user-specific directory for themes appear. It happens to be

```
~/.local/share/org.kde.syntax-highlighting
```

By analogy, since on my system the KDE's syntax highlighting files are located in

```
/usr/share/org.kde.syntax-highlighting/syntax/
```

I created the `syntax` directory in `~/.local/share/org.kde.syntax-highlighting/`.

The actual path may be different on your version of KDE/Kate, but you should be able to apply this procedure to find out what it is. You may also use something like `strace -e openat kate 2>&1 | grep syntax-highlighting` to list the files Kate actually opens (and, later, check whether your changes have the desired effect).

Then I used the `/usr/share/texmf-dist/asymptote/asy-kate.sh` script provided by Tex Live to generate the `asymptote.xml` syntax-highlighting description file and placed it in

```
~/.local/share/org.kde.syntax-highlighting/syntax/
```

That file already includes

```xml
<general>
        <comments>
                <comment name="singleLine" start="//" />
                <comment name="multiLine" start="/*" end="*/" region="Comment"/>
        </comments>
        <keywords casesensitive="1" />
</general>
```

that sets the string used by Kate to create comments when the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> key combination is pressed.

Now, if I open Kate, open a file and select "asymptote" in Tools → Mode → Sources or in Tools → Highlighting → Sources, the key combination to comment lines works as you are expecting.